# Displacement shrinking viewable plane

Tags: displacement

I'm trying to render a depth image with shadows. I use a grayscale depth image as an image texture which shows how far away pixel should be. I applied the displacement, but now my plane has shrunk. The left, right, and bit of the top of the view box do not line up with the sides.

I understand that in applying displacement the plane deforms in the Z-axis which takes some of the plane "fabric" away. What's the best way I can continue the plane so that the sides maintain the same depth of the background of the dog at the edges of the image?

Thanks in advance!
[image]